# Bug in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1

I was used to read **System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages** for enumerating list of installed keyboards for Farsi language.
But after updating to Windows 8.1, seems system returns all Farsi language keyboards as standard Persian, so I can't find if **my_custom_farsi_keyboard** is installed.

Is anything changed or am I missing something?

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage lang in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
            {
                if (lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == "my_custom_farsi_keyboard")
                    return lang;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Region and Lanuages kindly install the custom language keyboard. worked for me in case of Arabic (101).